# Is it possible to chop down trees?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

It's possible to attack plants and deal damage to them, and it's possible to dig through rock, but is it possible to cut down trees? I thought of using an axe but didn't have one to hand, and setting them on fire doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7):

A tree [is a form of wall](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Wall) internally. They can be destroyed by:

- Powerful fire magic (bolt of fire, bolt of magma, fireball, hellfire) or fire breath
- Lightning bolt
- Disintegration
- Shatter
- Orb of Destruction
- Corruption

Information on any other form of wall can be found on the aforementioned wiki.

Comment: Cheers! I'll test this the next time I find some trees.

Comment: The weakest spell that can destroy a tree is "Conjure Flame".

Comment: As far as I can tell, in the latest version (0.23.2), you cannot conjure a flame on a tree. Conjuring next to a tree dissipates after a few turns and the trees do not catch fire. I am disapoint.

Comment: Per that wiki, Conjure Flame could only burn trees prior to 0.15.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis To be fair, the answer was posted 4 months before 0.15 released.

Comment: @user1337 yep, and it's still useful information even today, since you can still [download 0.14 and earlier versions](https://crawl.develz.org/release/?C=N;O=D). So folks who like to run through the older versions can tell from this answer and comments that they can use Conjure Flame for trees; folks on 0.15-0.29 know that it won't work, and folks on 0.30+ don't have the spell anymore.